# Как извлечь в предложении следующие по порядку цифры?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется бот, который парсит сайт и выдает состояние заказа. Номер заказа - 9 цифр.

Каким образом можно извлечь 9 цифр по порядку в предложении, например:

```
"Найди мне номер заказа 123456789"
```

Если просто ввести 123456789 - функция отрабатывает, регулярка ловит 9 цифр и передает в функцию.

А как извлечь эти же 9 цифр (а их должно быть именно 9) из предложения, возможно разделенного запятыми, ума не приложу.

Comment: `\d{9}`........

Comment: if re.search(r'(^\d[0-9]{8}\b)', message.text):
        return search(message)

так то я понял как забрать 9 цифр, но только если введно 9 цифр и всё

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [115]: msg = "Найди мне номер заказа 123456789"

In [116]: re.findall(r"\b(\d{9})\b", msg)
Out[116]: ['123456789']
```

---

**UPD:**

```
def get_order_num(msg: str) -> str:
    r = re.findall(r"\b(\d{9})\b", msg)
    if r:
        return r[0]
    return None
```

тесты:

```
In [129]: get_order_num("Найди мне номер заказа 123456789")
Out[129]: '123456789'

In [130]: get_order_num("Найди мне номер заказа 12345")

In [131]: get_order_num("blah-blah")
```

Comment: if re.search(r'найди заявку|найти заявку|заявку', message.text):
        usr = re.findall(r'(\b(\d{9})\b)', message.text)
        #return search(usr)
        print(usr)
почему-то выводит список, дважды одно и тоже значение 123456789

Comment: хоть убейте не понимают, почему фраза "Найди мне номер заказа 123456789" после обработки re.findall возвращает мне список состоящий из 2 элементов, и как мне выбрать 1 значение?

Comment: @100parik, дополнил ответ